# Why add_custom_command does not work

Tags: cmake

I am trying to copy one file `${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/abc.h` to another location `{PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src` with the following command:

```
  add_custom_command(
        TARGET MyTarget
        POST_BUILD
        COMMAND -E copy ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/abc.h
        $<"${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src":MyTarget>)
```

However, no matter how I try, it seems that the created VC Studio project will not perform the file copy. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of issues.

First, you want to execute `cmake -E copy ...` inside the custom command.  To do this, you can provide the path to the CMake executable via the variable [`CMAKE_COMMAND`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#variable%3aCMAKE_COMMAND).

Next, you don't need generator expressions in this case.  You can just copy from `"${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/abc.h"` to `"${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src"`

So, your final command should be more like:

```
add_custom_command(
      TARGET MyTarget
      POST_BUILD
      COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/abc.h"
                                       "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src")
```

As an aside, if the copied file is forming part of your build, you might be better to use `cmake -E copy_if_different ...` rather than just `copy` since this won't update the copied file's timestamp needlessly.  (If the file is seen as "updated" all sources that `#include` it will be recompiled when a rebuild happens).